# how to reslove the issue in android studio Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-deep-link

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

i am try to restart,clear cache and update gradil dependency